# Meteor - createContainer reactive variable

Tags: javascript, meteor, amplifyjs

I'm trying to assign reactive data for `const date` here, so that lasted value gets propagate to my component via `this.props.date`

I'm using [amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/) to store user selected date to browser's local storage.

```
export default createContainer(() => {

  // Amplify Store
  const date = amplify.store( "date") || '';

  return { date};
}, sidePanel);
```

I can see that change value changes in browser's local storage, yet, `this.props.date` doesn't get updated.

Any idea if this is an acceptable approach?

I know, that Redux or similar library should be used, but it will be an over kill for this small project I'm working on.

Thanks

Comment: do you receive any new props in [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading, I have learned that meteor ships with number of reactive data sources:

- Session variables
- Database queries on Collections
- Meteor.status
- The ready() method on a subscription handle
- Meteor.user
- Meteor.userId
- Meteor.loggingIn

What I was doing in my question was using `createContainer` to prob an none reactive data source.

Meteor provides an API to create your own [custom reactive data source](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source).

However as a simple work around, I have used the [this package](https://github.com/cramrov/meteor-session-amplify) that extends meteor's Session variable and store it in browser's local storage via Amplify.

Its worth mentioning that Amplify comes with pub / sub system that is simple to use and can help wire up all front end events.